# Importing CSV files with relationship tables using List Manager

Tags: list-manager

I am trying to import **Lawyer.csv** which has a **LawyerID** for each lawyer, **LawyerLanguage.csv** which has **LanguageID** and **languageName**, and **LawyerLanguageRel.csv**. **LawyerLanguageRel** maps **LawyerIDs** to **LanguageIDs** to from the lawyer Language relationship table.

Is it possible to import **Lawyer.csv** and **LawyerLanguage.csv**, and form the Lawyer-Language relationship using the **List Manager** feature?

Here is a picture of the LawyerLanguage.csv and LawyerLanguageRel.csv,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible to import contacts from multiple csv files using `List Manager`.

What you can do instead, you can create a blank excel file, import from your 3 files using `Data` - `Import from CSV` into separate sheets in excel file.

Then create a 4th sheet in excel file and use excel formulas to get both Lawyer details and Language in one sheet.

Finally, export that 4th sheet into a csv file and import it to Sitecore using `List Manager`.

Comment: Thank you for the help.
 
I took a slightly different approach since List Manager allows you to upload only the columns: Email, Firstname and Lastname .
 
I ended up making an SQL Query to put all my sheets into one sheet, then used Sitecore Marketplace content export import tool by Erica Stockwell-Alpert to upload all the needed columns of my sheet.